# Log-on doesn't work from other Areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I am having problem invoking my Log-on action method, which is in a controller outside current Area.

I get the following error message :

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Is any way of calling the root controller that is outside areas in the main controller folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in an area, you'll need to specify a blank one to access your root controllers.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Home Controller", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Area in route parameters to ActionLink and other methods.